# importing PHP MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import database to phpmyadmin

the error is :-

---

""Error
Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

Variable name was expected. (near " " at position 5)
Variable name was expected. (near " " at position 26)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "Host" at position 0)
SQL query:

Host: localhost (Version: 5.6.16) # Date: 2015-06-03 23:46:52 # Generator: MySQL-Front 5.3 (Build 4.122) /'!40101 SET NAMES utf8 '/

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Host: localhost  (Version: 5.6.16)

## Date: 2015-06-03 23:46:52""

## Generator: My' at line 1

---

and the code :-

```
    # Host: localhost  (Version: 5.6.16)
# Date: 2015-06-03 23:46:52
# Generator: MySQL-Front 5.3  (Build 4.122)

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

#
# Structure for table "tbl_admin"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_admin` (
  `adm_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `adm_user` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adm_pwd` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`adm_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_admin"
#

INSERT INTO `tbl_admin` VALUES (1,'admin','21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3');

#
# Structure for table "tbl_answer"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_answer` (
  `ans_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `answer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quiz_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ans_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_answer"
#


#
# Structure for table "tbl_category"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_category` (
  `cat_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_category"
#

INSERT INTO `tbl_category` VALUES (4,'Programming','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod\r\ntempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,\r\nquis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo\r\nconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse\r\ncillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non\r\nproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',NULL);

#
# Structure for table "tbl_comment"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_comment` (
  `comment_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` text,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_comment"
#

INSERT INTO `tbl_comment` VALUES (1,'','2015-06-01 07:48:26',0,0),(2,'','2015-06-01 07:48:56',0,0);

#
# Structure for table "tbl_contact"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_contact` (
  `contact_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_contact"
#

INSERT INTO `tbl_contact` VALUES (2,'asd','sample@gmail.com',343,'sa','sadas'),(3,'asd','asdh@yahoo.com',324,'asd','asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'),(4,'Sample','asdh@yahoo.com',24,'asd','asd');

#
# Structure for table "tbl_quiz"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_quiz` (
  `quiz_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_name` text,
  `answer1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `answer2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answe3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`quiz_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_quiz"
#

INSERT INTO `tbl_quiz` VALUES (1,'<pre>\r\n<span style=\"color:rgb(0, 136, 0)\">What does PHP stand for?</span></pre>\r\n','4','','','',''),(2,'<pre>\r\n<span style=\"color:rgb(0, 136, 0)\">What does PHP stand for?</span></pre>\r\n','Personal Home Page','Personal Hypertext Processor','Private Home Page','PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor','4'),(3,'<p>asd</p>\r\n','asd','asd','asd','asd','3'),(4,'<p>asd</p>\r\n','45','45','45','452','2'),(5,'<p>asd</p>\r\n','gfgf','fg','fg','fg','2');

#
# Structure for table "tbl_subtopic"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_subtopic` (
  `sub_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sub_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_content` text,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `topic_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sub_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_subtopic"
#

INSERT INTO `tbl_subtopic` VALUES (1,'sample','<p><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/zg-J7jVNix0\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe></p>\r\n<p>asdasd</p>','2015-05-31 09:46:27',11),(2,'Lorem ipsum','<h3>sample</h3>\r\n\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />\r\ntempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br />\r\nquis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br />\r\nconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br />\r\ncillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br />\r\nproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>\r\n\r\n<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</div>\r\n\r\n<div>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</div>\r\n\r\n<div>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</div>\r\n\r\n<div>consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</div>\r\n\r\n<div>cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non</div>\r\n\r\n<div>proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>\r\n\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n\r\n<div><a href=\"http://iwantsourcecodes.com\" target=\"_blank\">http://iwantsourcecodes.com</a></div>\r\n','2015-05-31 06:00:53',11);

#
# Structure for table "tbl_teacher"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_teacher` (
  `teacher_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teacher_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_teacher"
#

INSERT INTO `tbl_teacher` VALUES (1,'sample','sample','sample','sample','sample'),(7,'lorems','lorem','lorem','lorem','lorem');

#
# Structure for table "tbl_topic"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_topic` (
  `topic_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `datetime_posted` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_topic"
#

INSERT INTO `tbl_topic` VALUES (11,'samples','<p><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/KmCkQEkeVn8\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe></p>\r\n<p>edited</p>','2015-05-16 10:10:49',3),(13,'sample','<p>sample</p>\r\n','2015-05-30 08:37:01',4);

#
# Structure for table "tbl_user"
#

CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
  `user_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yrlvl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#
# Data for table "tbl_user"
#

INSERT INTO `tbl_user` VALUES (1,'samples','sample','sample','2015-05-20','Male','BSIT','4','sample','5e8ff9bf55ba3508199d22e984129be6'),(2,'test','test','test','2015-05-08','Female','BSIT','1','test','098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'),(3,'aaa','aaa','aaa','2015-05-07','Male','BSCS','4','aaa','47bce5c74f589f4867dbd57e9ca9f808'),(4,'lorem','lorem','lorem','2015-04-30','Male','BSIT','2','lorem','d2e16e6ef52a45b7468f1da56bba1953');
```

---

Comment: Look like phpmyadmin see your comments as a SQL command, try removing your comments and import again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you checked that with Adminer ?

Comment: I don't get any error using the latest phpMyAdmin, either when entering your query or after running it. Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Do you get the message as a warning before submitting the query, or after running the query? If it's before, are you able to successfully run the query despite the warning (which usually is just a suggestion from the phpMyAdmin linter and doesn't restrict you from running the query).

Comment: i've already checked everything .. Same

Comment: isaac after running it !

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin, PHP, and MySQL versions are you using?

Comment: Your response isn't very clear about what exactly you tried or what the results were. Can you clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the commented parts of the code are causing the error. Delete those comments and give us the feedback.

Comment: Not Working ! Same